# Is the MongoDB Week Of The Year according to the ISO 8601 standard?

Tags: mongodb, iso8601

The [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/week/) states the `$week` aggregation and `%U` operator in `strftime` work like this:

> Returns the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.
>
> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the
>   year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. This
>   behavior is the same as the “%U” operator to the strftime standard
>   library function.

Does this conform to the [ISO 8601 week of the year standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Answer (score 3):

No. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) does not have week 0.

According to the standard:

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

...

> - If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01;
> - If 1 January is on a Friday, it is part of week 53 of the previous year;
> - If on a Saturday, it is part of week 52 (or 53 if the previous year was a leap year);
> - If on a Sunday, it is part of week 52 of the previous year.

There is an open ticket that suggests adding other options for week numeration; there's a suggestion for `$isoweek` in the comments:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7695